Should front brakes have this much give?
https://photos.app.goo.gl/uQdrppNmAwJsiyHk9
I never paid attention to how much give the brakes had when the bike was new.
The video shows the brakes clamped down onto the tire, and as I rock the bike either forward or backwards, there is some give.
Is this amount of give normal?

Sadly that level of wobble is not unusual for pressed-steel single pivot caliper brakes.
As long as the brake pad does not touch the tyre it is workable, though disconcerting.
You may be able to remove some play by slightly tightening the main bolt, but it still needs enough slack to actuate.   Another cause for play is worn bushings, and all the little bits of play in the system add up.
Another option is to upgrade the front caliper to a "dual pivot caliper" which should work with the same lever.  Make sure to choose one with enough "reach" to get down to the brake track.

My philosophy is that the main requirement is that your brakes should be adjusted so that they stop you safely.
Given you have safe braking, how tight they are is a matter of preference and how straight your wheel is.
